# Laravel 8: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object on One To Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, one-to-many, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8 to develop my project and in this project, I have applied **OneToMany** relationship between User Model and Role Model like this:

`User.php`:

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

`Role.php`:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
    }
```

Now I want to edit users, so at `edit.blade.php`, I added this line for getting name of the role that the user has:

`<option selected="selected">{{ $user->role->name }}</option>`

Note that I have already compacted the `user` at *edit* Method:

```
public function edit(User $user)
    {
        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('user'));
    }
```

And currently all of the users have a role id.

But now I get this error:

> **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: edit.blade.php)**

So what is wrong here ? How can I get the name of role that user has ?

Here is also the Migration of `roles` table if you wanna look at it:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And this is `add_fk_to_users_table` Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys about this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User.php` should be like this:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);// <--- this was your mistake. "Role" is correct!
}
```

And `Role.php`:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class); // <--- class should be "User" not "Role" here.
}
```

Comment: If it was helpful please hit the accepted button.  :)